# Use corner coordinates to create a tuple of all inner coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

If I have the following 4 sets of coordinates, each being a corner of a square, what would be the best way to create a coordinate mapping of all of the inner pixels?

```
(566, 282) - top left
(566, 304) - top right
(594, 282) - bottom left
(594, 304) - bottom right
```

Is there any python libraries to help create this box of pixels using the corner coordinates?

i.e expected result

```
[(566, 282), (566, 283), (566, 284)...(594, 302), (594, 303), (594, 304)]
```

Comment: use `range()` and `for` loops - you should do it in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only `for`, `range()` and list comprehension

```
left = 282
right = 304
top = 566
bottom = 594

result = [(y, x) for y in range(top, bottom+1) for x in range(left, right+1)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Just tried this out after reading your comment, works, thanks!